# What would be an approximate chance of human extinction from an asteroid crash

Tags: science-based, space, humans, earth, asteroids

I am writing a story about a goddam asteroid that would crash on Earth and put an end to humanity (Yes, this is kind of sad).

What are the scientific estimations today that this scenario is realisable?

Comment: This question is very unspecific. The sizes of the asteroid is very important. Also it's kinetic energy, material composition, etc. You need to elaborate on context and the aim of the question.

Comment: Sounds like you should be running some Google searches, rather than asking us. Had you done any research, you would know that we can't watch most of the sky, and that even if an asteroid were to hit the Earth, the outcome would be determined by how large it is, and _where it hits_. Voting to close as unclear. **Please do some research.**

Comment: In any particular year, roughly 1 in 100 million, going by the geological records of impacts and mass extinctions.

Answer (score 4):

A popular [analysis](http://users.physics.harvard.edu/~wilson/pmpmta/Mahoney_extinction.pdf) of human extinction includes:

> Based on the frequency of previous asteroid im-
>   pacts, the probability of an extinction-level (
>   ≥
>   10 km)
>   asteroid impact in this century is around one in 1 mil-
>   lion (Chapman, 2004; NASA, 2007).

However opinions differ on how unlikely that is:

> “Scientists have calculated that the chances of something so patently absurd actually existing are millions to one.
>   But magicians have calculated that million-to-one chances crop up nine times out of ten.”

― [Terry Pratchett, Mort](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/95458-scientists-have-calculated-that-the-chances-of-something-so-patently)